# Define css pack on build stage for Vue application

Tags: css, vue.js, npm

I have one single code-base for my Vue application, but for different end users I need to compile this application with different styles. Let's say in my `public` (or `assests`) folder I have subfolders with css for each single end user (by users in fact I mean a group/organization). So, I have subfolders like:

```
\public\user1\all.css
\public\user2\all.css
\public\user3\all.css
```

And when I build my application (`npm run build`) I need to apply somehow specific styles. Something, like

```
$ npm run build -css_path \public\user1\all.css
```

But I don not know, if it is technically possible and if I'm on the right track. Probably, it should be done some other way. So, what is the best practice to apply different styles to Vue application on the fly (on build or compilation stage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify environment variable with a particular value, in your case I think it would be `userN` values.

1. **If css files in the `public` directory**.
   Just reference your css file in `index.html` with environment variable:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= BASE_URL %><%= VUE_APP_MY_VARIABLE %>/all.css">
   ```

   And build with `VUE_APP_MY_VARIABLE=user1 npm run build`
2. **If css files in the `assets` directory**.
   Using the same env variable but we should import that css file in the top of the `main.js`(if you use default project structure):

   ```
   require('./assets/custom/' + process.env.VUE_APP_MY_VARIABLE + '/all.css');
   ```

   or

   ```
   import(/* webpackMode: "eager" */'./assets/custom/' + process.env.VUE_APP_MY_VARIABLE + '/all.css');
   ```

   And build with `VUE_APP_MY_VARIABLE=user1 npm run build` as well.

I also recommend to create `.env.local` with, for instance, `VUE_APP_MY_VARIABLE=user1` to be able to serve your local site and reference some default style to debug your app.

P.S. Check `cross-env` package which make your life easier with passing env variables. Because my build string is related to bash. With that package it would be cross platform:

```
cross-env VUE_APP_MY_VARIABLE=user1 npm run build
```

Comment: I did it like you advised in point 1. But for some stupid reason my css file is not loaded, but at the same time I see it in Inspector (inside header in DOM).

Comment: @Jacobian yeah, sorry, just add attributes to your `link`: `rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"`, I missed this in my example. I updated the answer as well.